# JQUERY assign id to jquery dialog button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

could one please advise me how i assign an id to a query button. I am using the query dialog modal form (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) - trying to style the button but it does not work

my query code:

```
buttons: {
      "Create an account": addUser,
      Cancel: function() {
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
    },
```

i tried adding it as the below but it did not work:

```
buttons: {
      "Create an account": { addUser,
        id: "account-btn"
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: if your trying to style the button add the id in your html. On that link you provided, if you click view source and then scroll to the very bottom youll see the buttons id is set in the html

Comment: the "create an account" button is not displayed - it's a hidden button which i am unsure how to access and style. You are referring to the "create new user" button but i am in search for the "create an account button" in order to add an id to style it

Comment: sorry didnt see that. actually looking at your code youre doing something strange with your button - answer added below

Answer (score 0):

They have a class of `ui-button`.  So you could just target them in CSS as so:

```
.dialogForm > .ui-button {  
    /* styles here */
}
```

or to target specific buttons

```
.dialogForm > .ui-button:nth-of-type(1) {
    /* targets the first button */
}
```

Similarly you can target them with JS and add the classes but it's messier.

- EDIT: If your trying to add an id for styling, please consider using classes instead.  However here's how you can add an id to the first button.  This is the markup that jQuery modal creates for the button view.

```js
$(function() {
  // If you want to target another button use 'button.ui-button:nth-child(INT)'.
  // Remove the selector and colon if you wish to target both.
  var $button = $('div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button.ui-button:first');

  // Adds id attribute.  The styling here is just to prove we're getting the right thing.
  $button.attr('id', 'uglyId');
  $button.css('background-color', 'pink');

  console.log($button.attr('id'));
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">

      <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Create an account</span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
      </button>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i was looking to target a specific button and wanted to know how to assign an id to that specific button as it's styling is different from the rest of the buttons

Comment: Replied.  FYI, use your DevTools or Firebug to look at the HTML markup.  You can then decide which elements have what props you can hook into.